# I'm trying to automate a code using Selenium. I'm unable to handle the dialog box elements

Tags: java

The code opens the dialog box but is not handling the dialog box elements. I've tried switching to the window but its not working.

Comment: Add some code snippets what you have done till now.

Comment: I got the solution. instead of switching windows, i used the xpath of each element of the dialog box to access it and enter text.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Use xpath of the dialog box elements to access it and use .sendKeys to enter text. Switching Windows didn't work for me. Using xpath worked!